# Occasional dialogue Boxes where all characters are question marks

Tags: macos, high-sierra, font, bug

Every so often, I get dialogue boxes that look like this:

[image]

Selected the text, pasted it into another editor, and lo and behold:

> “Slack” cannot be open during installation.
>
> Click Continue to quit “Slack” and begin the update. The application
>   will open when the update is complete.

So this is just one of those regular Mac App Store dialogues. I tried clearing the font caches with `sudo atsutil databases -remove`, to no avail.

Another other ideas for how to address this font corruption issue?

Comment: Slightly different question, but I think the answer ought to be the same.

Comment: @Tetsujin " I tried clearing the font caches with sudo atsutil databases -remove, to no avail."

Comment: but that is only the 2nd step of the other answer. Did you try both, from Recovery?

Comment: @Tetsujin I missed the `fontrestore default` command. I'll give it a shot!